# C#: Share local variable in 2 different threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

Look at this sample code :

```
private void StartProgram()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (true) // some conditions
        {
            int Temp = i; // every thread has different memory location for Temp variable.
            Thread ConnectThread = new Thread(ThreadMethod);
            ConnectThread.Start(Temp);
         }
    }
}

private static void ThreadMethod(object Index)
{
    int ID = (int)Index;
    int Result = 0;
    bool IsConnected;


    Result = ClientSMPP[ID].tcpConnect(Host[ID], int.Parse(Port[ID]));

    InsertToDatabaseMethod();
}
```

As I know, Temp variable has different location in memory for each thread. I mean every thread has a separate field for that. but when I want to do some actions in ThreadMethod, the ID field will conflict. I mean it doesn't have unique value in each time that ThreadMethod runs (for example ID's value is '1' 3 times). I know maybe more than 1 thread be in ThreadMethod, but they have different memory. I don't want to use Lock().

How Can I ignore this conflict?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking: do you want to _share_ the `int` across the multiple threads?

Comment: May be StartProgram method calls several time!

Comment: and "some conditions" is true for specific index.

Comment: @pb2q I dont want to share `int` across the multiple, but it dose.

Comment: @RezaArabQaeni if StartProgram method is called in several times, it shouldn't have shared variable. Its local and every time it has different location in stack. isnt it? and Im sure about `true condition`

Comment: @Elahe, when you generate same value(1..10) if method calls several time those threades must be same(not shared) value.

Comment: @RezaArabQaeni I found it. I have to use Lock() statement when I want to insert value to database

Comment: @Elahe, was about to post but I see you have a solution.  Just from my quick review, you're calling InsertToDatabaseMethod() without passing a value.  If the value being inserted is coming from an external source (Ex: a property), then yes, a lock is the way to go.  If the value is local (ex: your inserting "ID" into the database, then you can pass the value as a parameter to avoid the lock:  InsertToDatabaseMethod(ID)

Comment: @JFish222 Yes you are right. please Insert your comment as an answer for accepting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per your request, moving this response to an "answer".  Glad I could help! :)

You're calling InsertToDatabaseMethod() without passing a value.

If the value being inserted is coming from an external source (Ex: a property), then yes, a lock is the way to go.

If the value is local (ex: your inserting "ID" into the database, then you can pass the value as a parameter to avoid the lock: InsertToDatabaseMethod(ID)

Comment: Note, that the `Interlocked.Increment` Method would not require a `lock` if you just want to increment the variable in a cross-thread manner.https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd78zt0c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify it like this:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (true) // some conditions
        {                 
            Thread ConnectThread = new Thread(ThreadMethod);
            ConnectThread.Start(i);
        }
    }
```

Note that each thread has it's own stack.
Local variables are stored on the stack.

You have no issue because ints are value types.

Comment: but when I insert Index value to Database in ThreadMethod(), the records will be some thing like this: 1,1,1,2,2,2,5,6,8,8. I want to have this: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10. It shown than the index is shared and I dont know why...

Comment: Then you have something else wrong.  You can verify this by putting some debug/logging strings in the code.